# React update object value(quantity) for update db

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I have an item with a product number (details.quantityProduct) and a customer requested quantity (quantity).

After calculating its quantities (qtyDbUpdate) I would like to update (details.quantityProduct) but my function (changeQty) does not update this but adds an object (details) to newItems.

I do not understand. Please help me Thanks

```
const items = [{
  0: {id: "h72boj6td7o", quantity: 6, details: {… details.quantityProduct}}
  1: {id: "wx9pai7o04", quantity: 1, details: {…}}
  length: 2
}]

const qtyItems = (items.map(e => e))
const qtyCart = (qtyItems.map (f => (f.quantity) ))
const qtyDbUpdate = (qtyItems.map(f => (f.details.quantityProduct - qtyCart) ))

const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState(items)

  const changeQty = () => {
     setNewItems(newItems => ({
        ...newItems, details: {
           quantityProduct: qtyDbUpdate,
        }
     }))
  }
 console.log('newItems', newItems)
 newItems return :
   0: {id: "h72boj6td7o", quantity: 6, details: {…}}
   1: {id: "wx9pai7o04", quantity: 1, details: {…}}
   details:quantityProduct: (2) [NaN, NaN]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of things go wrong

```
const qtyDbUpdate = (qtyItems.map(f => (f.details.quantityProduct - qtyCart) ))
```

Here you try to subtract an array from array, the result of this operation is NaN

```
[3,4] - [1,2]===NaN
```

There is a problem with this aswell

```
 setNewItems(newItems => ({
    ...newItems, details: {
       quantityProduct: qtyDbUpdate,
    }
 }))
```

newItems is an array, but you create an object, if you destruct an array like that you'll get an object in a result, e.g.

```
const arr = ['a','b','c']
{...arr} === {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"} // this is what you get in a result
```

Just try

```
const changeQty = () => {
     setNewItems(items.map(item=>{
         const newProductQuantity=item.details.quantityProduct-item.quantity;
         return {
             ...item,
             details:{
                quantityProduct:newProductQuantity,
            }
         }
     }))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the lessons;)
I just made a small modification to have the value directly ```...item.details,quantityProduct: newProductQuantity ```